# difference between eclipse or android studio signed apk for play store

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, apk, signed-apk

first I created project in **Eclipse** and generated signed apk using **debug keystore** and uploaded to play store then  I have moved this project to **android studio** and done some changes and generated signed apk using **jks** file.

Now I want to upload it to play store does is work ? or May I face issue for apk. ?

**Note : Please do not downvote without reason.**
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't create new jks file for the same project ,as you have already uploaded apk with debug keystore and if you generate apk using new jks file play store won't allow you to upload apk

you can use same debug keystore while creating apk from android studio.for that you just have to click on "Choose Existing" and use same password that you have used while generating your first apk to be uploaded on play store

**Note:** Don't use debug keystore for generating signed APK because you are signing a release apk not the debug one

Comment: but for the eclipse I have created Debug keystore and uploaded play store  so what next step I used?

Comment: or how to create release apk in android studio without creating jks file

Comment: You can upload the apk using the same debug keystore. Just click "Choose Existing" in "generate signed apk" dialog and browse to your debug keystore path and use same password.

Comment: Even if you have created jks file , you can still generate the new signed apk again. Please Generate Signed APK again with your debug keystore

Answer (score 0):

Yes It'll work fine you'll not face any problem in uploading APK to PlayStore... both Eclipse and Android Studio Generated Same type to Signed Apk..

Thank You

Comment: As eclipse use debug key store and android studio use .jks file

Comment: not yet..but Yeah I asked my serious who has done this before... and they said that its not an issue.. both generate same APK